# Gaussian curvature and determinant with shape.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working on differential geometry and trying to do some calculations about gaussian curvature, my issue lies in that it defined
$$K(p)=\det(S_p)$$
Where $S_p$ is the shape operator defined as
$$S_p(Z)=-dN_p\cdot Z$$
First of as I understand the shape operator gives another vector so how is determinant defined for a vector here? I have only encountered for matrices.

Secondly, the $dN_p$ do I not know how to intepritate, does it mean derivative of the unit normal vector at point $p$ along $Z$ or what exactly?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

$S_P$ is a linear transformation (i.e., is represented by a matrix). Perhaps the dot in your equation is making things difficult. $S_P(Z) = -dN_p(Z)$ is (the negative of) the directional derivative of the unit normal in the direction of the tangent vector $Z$ at $P$. Take any curve $\alpha(t)$ on your surface with $\alpha(0)=P$ and $\alpha'(0)=Z$; then $S_P(Z) = -(N\circ\alpha)'(0)$.

(I don't know what text you are learning from. If you want another free resource, you might try my [lecture notes](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).)